# Black screen with GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm having a problem with getting a black screen with GLSL. I calculate my own projection matrix and modelview matrix on CPU and when I just use the plain GLSL code

```
void main() {            
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

it seems to work just fine. I load my matrixes into openGL and my image appears fine.
However as soon as I try and use this in my render section:

```
glUseProgram(p);
//glUseProgram(0);
//These were calculated and loaded into openGL before and they work.
float mod[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mod);
float proj[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, proj);
glUniformMatrix4fv(projMatrixLoc, 1, false, proj);
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrixLoc, 1, false, mod);
```

and this in my shader:

```
uniform mat4 modelview;
uniform mat4 projection;
void main() {            
mat4 mvp = projection * modelview;
gl_Position = mvp* gl_Vertex;
}
```

I get a black screen. I just don't get what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Is the `projection * modelview` in the right order? I always screw that up.

Comment: Order should be right, as long as matrices isn't transposed. Ensure uniform locations are correct. Ensure matrices are correct. If you absolutely sure with that, add actual values of `proj`, `mod` and several vertices coordinates to question.

Comment: Where is your fragment shader?

Comment: Where's your `#version` directive?

Comment: The `transpose` argument to `glUniformMatrix4fv()` should be `GL_TRUE` or `GL_FALSE`, not `true` or `false`.